# Modify existing block programmatically by block id

Tags: blocks

I have a block with the id 'block-block-8'. In my template.php I would like to have a function that changes that block's content so I am able to add a dynamic "back to category link" (category needs to come frome the url) on my products page back to the category page.

Something like this:

```
function ga2012_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'block-block-8':
      $block = array(
        'content' => '<a href="/order/4/workshops">Back to $_GET["category"]</a>',
      );
      break;
  }

  return $block;
}
```

Does someone has a working implementation of this code? Please ask me questions if I haven't been clear enough, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You might try with [hook_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter/7) which:

> Performs alterations to a specific block

Comment: I enabled the PHP filter module and added the PHP code into the block via the admin interface. This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, the best solution is to use hook_block_view_MODULE_DELTA_alter  as @Artur explained. But there is another way to to customize a custom bloc programmatically using an update function (inside a .install file) in drupal 7 by using:

```
$content = 'your new content';

$num_update = db_update('block_custom')
                ->fields(['body' => $content,])
                ->condition('bid', your_block_id, '=')
                ->execute();
```